# Why does std::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours::max()) return immediately on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++-chrono, compiler-bug

I was running a C++ program that provides a service, and noticed that it was taking 100% of a CPU even when serving no requests.  I narrowed the problem down to a while loop which calls `std::sleep_for` in order to prevent the service from exiting.

To test, I compiled and ran this simple test program:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours::max());
}
```

My expectation was that this would sleep for a very long time, and indeed when I tried it on my M1 Mac I saw the expected behavior.  However when I ran it on a Redhat Linux 8 machine it returned immediately.  I also tried it on a Rocky Linux 8 docker container, running on the Mac, and this also returned immediately.  This confirms that this occurs on RHEL 8 systems in general - or at least with gcc 8.5.0, since that compiler version is the same on both linux systems (the compiler on the Mac is the Apple-provided clang).

This explains why my service was taking 100% of CPU, since it was calling this in a while loop.  But I've never heard of this behavior.  Has anyone else?

Of course, I can easily solve the problem by sleeping for `std::chrono::seconds(1)`.  I'm only asking this question out of intellectual curiosity.

Comment: I have run into it during toolchain validation testing. The cause was integer overflow in the implementation, either in the C++ standard library implementation of `sleep_for()` or the underlying libc implementation it is implemented on, depending on the C++ standard library implementation and the target libc. It can be both.

Comment: FWIW I can reproduce this on newer versions as well.  Looks like it is a `libstdc++` issue: https://godbolt.org/z/z3G4hvvY7

Comment: Well, if I ever decide to ask one of my execution threads to stop until the heat death of the universe, I suppose I can't complain, much, if it adamantly refuses to do so...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in libstdc++ https://godbolt.org/z/vce44vjx5, looks like an overflow.

It inlines `nanossleep()` call with

```
timespec req{ -3600, 0 };  // -1 hour.
```

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], -3600
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], 0
        mov     rbx, rsp
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rdi, rbx
        mov     rsi, rbx
        call    nanosleep@PLT
```

Comment: `libstdc++` issue reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113327